# How to force inline elements to stay one same line?

Tags: html, css

I have the following code

```css
You also can try this: div {
  padding: 5px;
}

.father {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
}

.child {
  display: inline-block;
}

.red {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}

.blue {
  background: blue
}
```

```html
<div class="father">
  <div class="child red">
    I am red red red red red red red red
  </div>
  <div class="child blue">
    I am blue
  </div>
  <div class="child red">
    I am red
  </div>
  <div class="child blue">
    I am blue
  </div>
</div>
```

How to align them this way, so when one of the blocks contain multiline text, the next one is rendered from the point where the previous one has ended? 
[image]

Comment: Actually use `display: inline` instead of `display: inline-block`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `inline-block` use `inline`

```css
You also can try this: div {
  padding: 5px;
}

.father {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
}

.child {
  display: inline;
}

.red {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}

.blue {
  background: blue
}
```

```html
<div class="father">
  <div class="child red">
    I am red red red red red red red red
  </div>
  <div class="child blue">
    I am blue
  </div>
  <div class="child red">
    I am red
  </div>
  <div class="child blue">
    I am blue
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
div.father {
  padding: 5px;
  width: 200px;
}

span.red {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}

span.blue {
  background: blue
}
```

and

```
   <div class="father">
     <p class='child'>
       <span class="red"> I am red red red red red red red red </span>   
       <span class="blue"> I am blue blue blue </span>   
       <span class="red"> I am red red red </span>
     </p>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Straighforward solution is to replace the child divs with spans as below, all then renders as expected:

```css
div {
  padding: 5px;
}

.father {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
}

.child {
  /* removed unnecessary styles here */
}

.red {
  background: red;
  color: white;
}

.blue {
  background: blue
}
```

```html
<div class="father">
  <span class="child red">
    I am red red red red red red red red
  </span>
  <span class="child blue">
    I am blue
  </span>
  <span class="child red">
    I am red
  </span>
  <span class="child blue">
    I am blue
  </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

make your father class width 100% then all your content will inline-block.
otherwise you can use this code.

```css
 div {
            padding: 5px;
        }
        
        .father {
            display: block;
            width: 100%;
        }
        
        .child {
            display: inline-block;
        }
        
        .red {
            background: red;
            color: white;
        }
        
        .blue {
            background: blue
        }
```

```html
<div class="father">
        <div class="child red">
            I am red red red red red red red red
        </div>
        <div class="child blue">
            I am blue
        </div>
        <div class="child red">
            I am red
        </div>
        <div class="child blue">
            I am blue
        </div>
    </div>
```